# Poco and openssl linker error with visual studio 2010 c++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, openssl, poco-libraries

Trying to link with the static library of Poco throws the following error

```
1>PocoNetSSLmd.lib(SSLManager.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol X509_verify_cert_error_string
1>PocoNetSSLmd.lib(Utility.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol X509_verify_cert_error_string
```

But the libeay32.lib static library to which the project is linked contains the symbols

```
$ dumpbin /ALL libeay32.lib | grep X509_STORE_CTX_get_error
    915B6 _X509_STORE_CTX_get_error
    915B6 __imp__X509_STORE_CTX_get_error
    9162E _X509_STORE_CTX_get_error_depth
    9162E __imp__X509_STORE_CTX_get_error_depth
      92C _X509_STORE_CTX_get_error
      92D _X509_STORE_CTX_get_error_depth
      92C __imp__X509_STORE_CTX_get_error
      92D __imp__X509_STORE_CTX_get_error_depth
  Symbol name  : _X509_STORE_CTX_get_error
  Symbol name  : _X509_STORE_CTX_get_error_depth
          1016    _X509_STORE_CTX_get_error
          1017    _X509_STORE_CTX_get_error_depth
```

The preprocessor symbols **POCO_STATIC, POCO_NO_UNWINDOWS, POCO_HAVE_IPv6** are set in the project settings.

How to resolve the issue.

Comment: Are you sure that _libeay32.lib_ is specified to the linker? Or at least that the one that you ran _dumpbin_ on, is the one included (its path it's the 1'st one in the linker _/LIBPATH:_ entries)?

Answer (score 1):

In your Project Properties, on the Linker page, add the path to your POCO libraries to the "**Additional Library Entries**" page.
Also, on Properties > General > Use of MFC, select "**Use MFC in a Static Library**"

Depending on which POCO libs you are using, you will probably have to add paths for Poco/Foundation and at least one other POCO lib.